# Exponential family and efficient estimator

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimators, exponential-family, efficiency

In my lecture notes there is the notion of efficiency related to the exponential family. More precisely, the lecturer stated that for an exponential family an efficient estimator always exists. How is it possible to prove this without specifying explicitly the distribution? Should I use Cramer-Rao? I'm not able to do at this level of generality.

Comment: by efficient, does he mean reach the CR lower bound ? If not, then it's not clear what efficient means because it's usually a relative term.

Comment: Yes, it means variance equals to the CR lower bound.

Comment: Hi:  I didn't read it but this looks useful. https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a0ce/176094127756e8a5c2a1e1896e0fb18f9e8b.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You could just take a general pdf dependent on some parameter $\theta$ such as $f(x; \theta)$ and derive the result from there.

The key insight indeed comes from the derivation of the Cramér-Rao bound which makes use of the linear correlation coefficient between the score $S$ and the parameter estimator $\hat{\theta}$ (check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound#A_standalone_proof_for_the_general_scalar_case)).

The squared linear correlation coefficient is always less than  1. The equality implies a linear relationship between $S$ and $\hat{\theta}$, ie, $$S = m'(\theta)\hat{\theta} + b'(\theta) \tag 1,$$ where $m'(\theta)$ and $b'(\theta)$ denote the derivatives of some functions which depend only on $\theta$.

Now, the score is defined as $$S = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \ln f(x; \theta) \tag 2.$$

Equating (1) with (2),

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \ln f(x; \theta) = m'(\theta)\hat{\theta} + b'(\theta)$$

Integrating over $\theta$ and taking the long of both sides of the equation yields

$$\ln f(x; \theta) = \int m'(\theta) \hat{\theta}(x) + b'(\theta) d\theta \Leftrightarrow$$

$$\ln f(x; \theta) = m(\theta) \hat{\theta}(x) + b(\theta) + c(x) \Leftrightarrow$$

$$f(x; \theta) = \exp[ \ m(\theta) \hat{\theta}(x) + b(\theta) + c(x) \ ]$$

If whatever pdf $f(x; \theta)$ can be written in that form (exponential family form) than we can say that our estimator is efficient (there are some assumptions being made in this derivation, namely that conditions required for the Cramér-Rao bound are met).

Comment: Welcome to CV, Daniela!

Comment: Thank you for the clean up and for the welcome! It was about time I went from just reading to contributing a bit